# How to make a dynamic array of Eigen::Map objects, since they don't have a default constructor?

Tags: c++, eigen

I need to make a **dynamic** array of Eigen::map objects. How can i do it since that object has no default constructor? I was thinking something like `Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd> a[Num_of_Maps];` which i will be able to initialise later, maybe with `new`.

I am not trying to get a workaround solution that will have the same effect, although if you have one, i would like to know it.

Also, i am not asking for a solution so drastic as to extend the Eigen library to make a default constructor, as that would have further implications. However, if you have such a solution, you are also welcome to post it.

Comment: Can you provide us with some code? You can achieve what you want with `std::vector`.

Comment: Here is an example of using `std::vector` with objects in general: https://ideone.com/McvpYg. You can do the same to Eigen::map

Comment: @Gasim I think it will not work, since this approach requires the object in question to have a default constructor. The Eigen::Map object has no default constructor, and the constructor it has needs the parameters at the time of creation. I will try it, and post about the results. In the mean time, i am still looking for a way that it is not a workaround!

Comment: I tried your code and it works, and i also have found another approach that works!

Comment: There were two ways that came to my mind: Array of Pointers (not Objects!) and C++ Containers that hold objects. The latter one provided a much cleaner approach to your problem.